# Fancybox - Combining images and iframes in one gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have an "attached files" container in a project I'm working on which shows thumbnail images of files that have been attached to a specific event. When a user clicks a thumbnail, a fancybox window opens up to show them a larger preview of the attached image or text file.

Right now, my solution consists of setting the fancybox type to iframe, like so:

```
$(".fancybox_group").fancybox({
    type : 'iframe'
});
```

This will display both text files and images just fine, but the images have this giant white border around them. I did some searching on google and found [this solution](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/2ff36b598a095628), but it doesn't work for me. This simply creates two separate fancybox instances; one for images, and one for iframes. I would like to be able to scroll through all of the attachments in one gallery. Is this possible?

[Here is an example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T4XLs/1/) showing what I'm trying to achieve. I borrowed the code/images from a fancybox example and added another thumbnail link to a text document. This is how I have it set up in my project. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using fancybox v2.0.6 so other solutions may be obsolete.

To achieve what you want is simple, just do:

1). Load all javascript files in this order:

- jQuery
- Fancybox js file
- Fancybox media js file (you find this within the helpers directory)

2). Load the fancybox css file

3). Set the `html` for each type of object you want to open in fancybox like:

Images :

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="image01.jpg"><img src="image01thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="image02.jpg"><img src="image02thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

If the `href` of your images is something like `href='/attachments/76'` fancybox won't know it is an `image` because the lack of extension (jpg,png,gif). Add the class `fancybox.image` to your html like :

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.image" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="/attachments/76"><img src="thumb76.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Ajax content (html or txt files) :

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="sample.html">open ajax 1</a>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="sample.txt">open ajax 2</a>
```

(notice the second class `fancybox.ajax` ... also, you could use thumbnails instead of the text in my example)

External pages via iframe :

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="http://domain.com/page.html">open page in iframe mode</a>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="http://other.com/page2.html">open other page in iframe mode</a>
```

(notice the second class `fancybox.iframe`)

Youtube videos :

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2matH4B9bTo">open youtube video</a>
```

(notice that we don't need to add any additional class since we are using fancybox media helper)

**NOTE**: we are using the `data-fancybox-group="gallery"` attribute to set all the elements within the same gallery (you should set a HTML5 `DOCTYPE` though)

Finally, simply use this script:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

You may want to add other API options like:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  // other API options
  padding: 0 // optional etc.
});
```

If you additionally want to use the `buttons` or `thumbnails` helpers don't forget to load the proper js and css files. Also add the `helpers` options to your script like:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox(
 helpers : {
  buttons : {},
  thumbs : {
   width : 50,
   height : 50
  }
 }
});
```

**LAST NOTE**: this is fancybox v2.0.6+

Comment: I think this will work, but I'm struggling with something on my end. I'm retrieving images that are stored at a url, so the `href` is in the format of `href='/attachments/76'`. Fancybox won't even fire if I click on an image, but if I click on anything with a class `fancybox fancybox.iframe` it works just fine. Any idea on how I can work around this? Any other time, I had to explicitly set the fancybox `type` to `image`.

Comment: because your URL has not an image extension (jpg,png,gif) you have to tell fancybox it's an image. You could create a separated script for those images and add the option `type: "image"` like `$(".fancy_image").fancybox({type: "image"});`

Comment: That's what I figured was the issue, but now when I add `$('.fancy_image).fancybox({type: "image"});` after my normal `$(".fancybox").fancybox();` script, images still won't show. Do I need to change something in my first call to fancybox?

Comment: BTW, keeping the same `data-fancybox-group="gallery"` will also include the images within the gallery regardless they use another script with another `class`

Comment: I'm still not having success with this. I really do appreciate you taking the time to help me though. Even keeping the `data-fancybox-group="gallery"` the same on all links, it will only display `iframe` content and no images. If I have two separate `.fancybox()` calls, it'll display 2 different galleries.

Comment: Hey! Good news! It works now. All that needed changed was adding a class `fancybox.image` to the links that were for images. I think that's what you were getting at a few comments ago, but I got confused by the `fancybox_image` class comment. THANKS so much! I owe you one!

Comment: glad to hear, I will put a note to my answer in case somebody faces the same issue. Thanks for the feedback.